# Calling functions outside paths

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

In mongojs, when you do:

```
var birds = db.birds.find(searchTerm, callback);
```

...how do you pass arguments to the callback? I've tried bind, as in:

```
birds = db.birds.find(searchTerm, app.get('getBirds').bind(res));
```

...but to no avail. Just fyi I'm trying to pass the response object of the GET route so that the callback can render using res.send(results).

The other option is to set app.set('res': res); and call app.get('res') from the callback - I'm not sure this is a good idea. It works, but it doesn't obey the events loop model too well - I think the request back to the app may be costly? Any help would be gratefully accepted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically do this by wrapping the `callback` function call in an anonymous function:

```
db.birds.find(searchTerm, function (err, birds) {
    callback (err, birds, res);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how it's done:

     birds = db.birds.find(searchTerm, function(err, birds)    {app.get('renderResults')(err, birds, res)});

Well done fella. :)

Answer (score 1):

To be sure what you are trying to accomplish:

Is your intent to use the results of the `find` call in your response from the server?  You could wrap the `find` in a function that takes in the response as a parameter, and then define the callback to the `find` with the response accessed inside it.

For example (untested code, but this is the idea):

```
// function called when a request is received
function getBirds(searchTerm, res) {
    birds = db.birds.find(searchTerm, function(err, docs) {
        // code in here will have access to res because it is in a closure
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @shelman,
db.birds.find() is a method which takes a nosql query (here denoted by the variable 'searchTerm') and executes it on the 'birds' collection within your database ('db'). You pass it a callback function so that when it retrieves the data from the query it will then execute that callback function, this is in keeping with the node event loop idea to prevent blocking. Because I'm using the same callback for all my app.get routes, I set it as a function (called 'getBirds') within the app. The problem is that because it was defined outside the GET response it has no access to the res obj

Comment: Yes. What you've outlined is how it originally was. The function that you've called getBirds is what I have in my script as the function that is called when that route is requested. I had the same code as you but if you imagine that I have say 10 different routes then I'm writing out the same code (at the point where you have the comment) ten times over. This is why I extracted it and saved it in the app so that I only had it written once. The issue, as I mentioned, is that because it's now created outside of the GET functions, it has no access to the res obj.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to pass parameters to a callback - I would recommend defining the function anonymously with the res object passed in.